# How to pass specific UserContext in unit testing of controller action

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following controller action

```
        [Route(ActionName.Create)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
        {
            .... 
            if (!UserContext.Roles.HasFlag(GroupsEnum.Admin))
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Permission Denied");
            }
            ... 
        }
```

I have following in xxxxControllerTests.cs

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Can_Request_Create()
        {

            ViewResult result = (ViewResult)await MockController.Object.Create();
            ...
            ...
        }
```

when I run the unit test I get unauthorized access exception raised. How can pass UserContext while mockController, so controller action will be executed with specific user context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you're instantiating the Controller you're testing, you can initialize it like this:

```
var controllerToTest = new MyController() {
    ControllerContext = new ControllerContext {
        HttpContext = //assign mock context,
        UserContext = //assign mock context
    }
};
var result = controllerToTest.Create();
```

However this line of code makes me think you're testing an already mocked controller:

```
ViewResult result = (ViewResult)await MockController.Object.Create();
```

The `.Object` call makes me think you have a `Mock<MyController>` in there and that's not right. You're not testing your own controller.

Comment: Thanks, @Simmetric, clue you provided give me an idea of how to fix it. all fixed now :). I will update the question with the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should Mock your dbContext.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219742/mocking-ef-core-dbcontext-and-dbset][1]