# I need a way to Unit Test my command handlers in asp.net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

This is my Unit Tests file.

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Moq;
using QueryStore.Application.Common;
using QueryStore.Application.Queries;
using QueryStore.Domain;

namespace QueryStore.Application.UnitTests.Queries.Commands;

public class CreateQueryCommandHandlerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<QueryStoreDbContext> _contextMock = new();
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<CreateQueryCommandHandler>> _loggerMock = new();
    
    private readonly IValidator<CreateQueryCommand> _validator = new CreateQueryCommandValidator();

    [Fact]
    public void Handle_Should_ReturnValidationErrorWithErrorMessage_WhenNameIsEmpty()
    {
        var command = new CreateQueryCommand()
        {
            Name = "",
            Content = "Select * From TableName",
            Description = "Some description about the query.",
            Tags = new[] { "company", "import" }
        };

        var validationResult = _validator.Validate(command);

        Assert.False(validationResult.IsValid);
        Assert.Contains("'Name' must not be empty.", validationResult.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void Handle_Should_ReturnValidationErrorWithErrorMessage_WhenContentIsEmpty()
    {
        var command = new CreateQueryCommand()
        {
            Name = "Some Name",
            Content = "",
            Description = "Some description about the query.",
            Tags = new[] { "company", "import" }
        };

        var validationResult = _validator.Validate(command);

        Assert.False(validationResult.IsValid);
        Assert.Contains("'Content' must not be empty.", validationResult.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void Handle_Should_ReturnValidationErrorWithErrorMessage_WhenTagsAreNotAlphanumeric()
    {
        var command = new CreateQueryCommand()
        {
            Name = "Some Name",
            Content = "",
            Description = "Some description about the query.",
            Tags = new[] { "company#2%", "import" }
        };

        var validationResult = _validator.Validate(command);

        Assert.False(validationResult.IsValid);
        Assert.Contains("Query tags must be alphanumeric, lowercase tags separated by commas.", validationResult.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void Handle_Should_ReturnNoValidationErrors_WhenQueryIsValid()
    {
        var command = new CreateQueryCommand()
        {
            Name = "Some Name",
            Content = "Select * from AbcCompany",
            Description = "Some description about the query.",
            Tags = new[] { "company", "import" }
        };

        var validationResult = _validator.Validate(command);

        Assert.True(validationResult.IsValid);
    }

    
    [Fact]
    public async Task Handle_Should_ReturnSuccessResult_WhenQueryIsAddedToDatabase()
    {
        var command = new CreateQueryCommand()
        {
            Name = "Some Name",
            Content = "Select * from AbcCompany",
            Description = "Some description about the query.",
            Tags = new[] { "company", "import" }
        };
        
        _contextMock.Setup(x => x.Queries.Add(It.IsAny<Query>()));

        var handler = new CreateQueryCommandHandler(_contextMock.Object, _validator, _loggerMock.Object);

        var validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(command);

        var result = await handler.Handle(command, CancellationToken.None);

        _contextMock.Verify(x => x.Queries.Add(It.IsAny<Query>()), Times.Once);

        _contextMock.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None), Times.Once);
    
        Assert.True(validationResult.IsValid);
        Assert.IsType<Result<int>>(result);
        Assert.True(result.IsSuccess);
        Assert.True(result.Value > 0);
    }
}
```

My Command Handler Code:

```
using FluentValidation;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using QueryStore.Application.Common;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace QueryStore.Application.Queries;

internal sealed class CreateQueryCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateQueryCommand, Result<int>>
{
    private readonly QueryStoreDbContext _context;

    private readonly IValidator<CreateQueryCommand> _validator;

    private readonly ILogger _logger;


    public CreateQueryCommandHandler(
        QueryStoreDbContext context,
        IValidator<CreateQueryCommand> validator,
        ILogger<CreateQueryCommandHandler> logger)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _validator = validator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(validator));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public async Task<Result<int>> Handle(CreateQueryCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            return Result.Error(validationResult.Errors.Select(e => new Error($"{e.PropertyName}", e.ErrorMessage)));
        }

        try
        {
            var entity = request.AsQuery();

            _context.Add(entity);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

            return Result<int>.Success(entity.Id);
        }
        catch (DbException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while saving query to database");

            return Result.Error(new Error("error", ex.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An unknown error occurred while saving query");

            return Result.Error(new Error("error", ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i get currently:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: x => x.Queries

System.NotSupportedException
Unsupported expression: x => x.Queries
Non-overridable members (here: QueryStoreDbContext.get_Queries) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
   at Moq.Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression) in /_/src/Moq/Guard.cs:line 99
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|5_0(Expression e, Expression& r, MethodExpectation& p, Boolean assignment, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in /_/src/Moq/ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 191
   at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in /_/src/Moq/ExpressionExtensions.cs:line 170
   at Moq.Mock.SetupRecursive[TSetup](Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Func`4 setupLast, Boolean allowNonOverridableLastProperty) in /_/src/Moq/Mock.cs:line 728
   at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition) in /_/src/Moq/Mock.cs:line 562
   at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression) in /_/src/Moq/Mock`1.cs:line 645
   at QueryStore.Application.UnitTests.Queries.Commands.CreateQueryCommandHandlerTests.Handle_Should_ReturnSuccessResult_WhenQueryIsAddedToDatabase() in Application/tests/Queries/Commands/CreateQueryCommandHandlerTests.cs:line 96
   at Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker`1.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<<InvokeTestMethodAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestInvoker.cs:line 264
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExecutionTimer.AggregateAsync(Func`1 asyncAction) in /_/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/ExecutionTimer.cs:line 48
   at Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAggregator.RunAsync(Func`1 code) in /_/src/xunit.core/Sdk/ExceptionAggregator.cs:line 90
```

I have a command handler CreateQueryCommandHandler I want to Write Unit Tests for this handler. It takes DbContext as an argument. But when i mock the Add Method it throws an error. I need a way to test my command handlers without using repository pattern.

Comment: Property `QueryStoreDbContext.Queries` is not overridable, so it could not be mocked. Only overridable methods could be mocked, because Moq works with inheritance under the hood. Assuming it's EF Core DB context, I would recommend using special nugets for DbContext mocking, for example https://github.com/MichalJankowskii/Moq.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: There's an in-memory provider you can use for testing.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219742/mocking-ef-core-dbcontext-and-dbset) might be helpful.